# Flattening an array in SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I am trying to flatten this array so that each neighbor has its own column.

How do I write a query that allows me to flatten this array when I don't know the elements in the array?

```
SELECT deviceid,
       neighbors
FROM
      `etl.routing_table_nodes`
WHERE
       Parent = 'QMI-YSK'
```

And results currently look like:

```
Row deviceid    neighbors    
1    OHX-ZSI    DMR-RLE  
                WMI-YEK  
2    OHX-ZFI    DMR-RLE  
                QMI-YSK
```

[Bigquery screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOPNH.png)

Comment: Can you add the schema for the table? Is `neighbors` a nested column?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT
    deviceid, unnested_neighbors
FROM 
    `etl.routing_table_nodes` table,
    UNNEST(table.neighbors) as unnested_neighbors
WHERE
    unnested_neighbors = 'QMI-YSK'
```